# Redux dispatch causing useEffect re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I'm building an e-commerce website, but ran into a problem when using redux to dispatch action.
There's a "Add to cart button" on the product detail page, the button will dispatch "addItemToCart" action, the problem is that dispatch causes useEffect re-render even the useEffect doesn't have any dependency, but this doesn't happen when dispatching same action in the other component.

The sendRequest in useEffect is from useHttp hook, it's wrapped in useCallbak.

I tried the cleanup function in useEffect but doesn't work.

**Redux:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    totalQuantity: 0,
    totalAmount: 0,
    isChanged: false,
  },
  reducers: {

    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      state.isChanged = true;
      state.totalAmount = (
        state.totalAmount * 1 +
        action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity
      ).toFixed(2);
      state.totalQuantity += action.payload.quantity;

      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);

      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push(action.payload);
      } else {
        // If product is added then update product quantity
        existingItem.quantity += action.payload.quantity;
      }
    },

    deleteItemFromCart(state, action) {
      state.isChanged = true;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload
      );
      state.totalQuantity -= existingItem.quantity;
      state.totalAmount = (
        state.totalAmount * 1 -
        existingItem.price * existingItem.quantity
      ).toFixed(2);

      state.items = state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== existingItem.id);
    },

    decreaseItemQuantity(state, action) {
      state.isChanged = true;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload
      );

      state.totalAmount = (state.totalAmount * 1 - existingItem.price).toFixed(
        2
      );
      state.totalQuantity--;

      if (existingItem.quantity === 1) {
        // Remove product from cart if quantity is qual to  1
        state.items = state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== existingItem.id);
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity--;
      }
    },

    emptyCart(state) {
      state.isChanged = true;
      state.items = [];
      state.totalAmount = 0;
      state.totalQuantity = 0;
    },

    setCartState(state, action) {
      state.isChanged = false;
      state.items = action.payload.items;
      state.totalAmount = action.payload.totalAmount;
      state.totalQuantity = action.payload.totalQuantity;
    },
  },
});
```

**Product Page Component:**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Rating } from "@mui/material";
import TwitterIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Twitter";
import FacebookIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Facebook";
import InstagramIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Instagram";
import PinterestIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Pinterest";
import LocalShippingOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocalShippingOutlined";
import useHttp from "../hooks/use-http";
import { cartActions } from "../store/cart-slice";
import Loader from "../components/UI/Loader";
import styles from "../sass/pages/ProductDetail.module.scss";

function ProductDetail() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { httpState, sendRequest } = useHttp();
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    sendRequest(`/products/${productId}`);
  }, [sendRequest, productId]);

  const decreaseProductHandler = () => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity - 1);
  };
  const increaseProductHandler = () => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity + 1);
  };

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    dispatch(cartActions.addItemToCart({ ...httpState.data, quantity }));
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles["product-detail"]}>
      {httpState.loading && <Loader />}
      {!httpState.loading && httpState.data && (
        <>
          <div className={styles["product-detail__img-box"]}>
            <img src={httpState.data.image} alt={httpState.data.title} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles["product-detail__info"]}>
            <h2 className={styles["product-detail__title"]}>
              {httpState.data.title}
            </h2>

            <div className={styles["product-detail__rating"]}>
              <Rating
                name="half-rating-read"
                defaultValue={5}
                value={httpState.data.rating.rate}
                precision={0.5}
                readOnly
              />
              <span>{httpState.data.rating.count} reviews</span>
            </div>
            <div className={styles["product-detail__icons"]}>
              <TwitterIcon />
              <FacebookIcon />
              <InstagramIcon />
              <PinterestIcon />
            </div>

            <p className={styles["product-detail__price"]}>
              ${httpState.data.price}
            </p>
            <div className={styles["product-detail__shipping"]}>
              <LocalShippingOutlinedIcon />
              <span>Free Shipping</span>
            </div>

            <div className={styles["product-detail__actions"]}>
              <span
                role="button"
                className={`${styles["product-detail__actions--decrease"]} ${
                  quantity <= 1 ? styles["product-detail__actions--hide"] : ""
                }`}
                onClick={decreaseProductHandler}
              >
                -
              </span>

              <span>Quantity: {quantity}</span>
              <span
                role="button"
                className={styles["product-detail__actions--increase"]}
                onClick={increaseProductHandler}
              >
                +
              </span>
            </div>

            <button
              className={styles["product-detail__btn"]}
              onClick={addToCartHandler}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>

            <div className={styles["product-detail__description"]}>
              <h3>DESCRIPTION:</h3>
              {httpState.data.description}
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

**useHttp hook:**

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from "react";
import { mainAxios } from "../axios";

const initialHttpState = { loading: false, error: null, data: null };

const httpReducer = (httpState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SEND": {
      return {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: null,
      };
    }

    case "RESPONSE": {
      return {
        ...httpState,
        loading: false,
        data: action.data,
      };
    }

    case "ERROR": {
      return { loading: false, error: action.errorMessage };
    }

    default: {
      throw new Error("Invalid action");
    }
  }
};

const useHttp = () => {
  const [httpState, dispatchHttp] = useReducer(httpReducer, initialHttpState);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (url) => {
    try {
      dispatchHttp({ type: "SEND" });
      const res = await mainAxios.get(url);

      const data = res.data;

      dispatchHttp({ type: "RESPONSE", data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatchHttp({ type: "ERROR", errorMessage: err.message });
    }
  }, []);

  return {
    httpState,
    sendRequest,
  };
};

export default useHttp;
```

Comment: Hey There so why do you have sendRequest as a dependancy of the useEffect ? so what could be happening is that youre updating some state of the parent this component is in so your component is probably re rendering. so when the re render occurs the sendRequest is a new reference I could be wrong but this is all I can pick up from the code I see :D

Comment: Hi,I added the code of useHttp hook in the question, the sendRequest is from useHttp , it's wrapped in useCallbak, so this shouldn't be the problem?